# Managing application configuration in a chef environment cookbook

Tags: deployment, configuration, chef-infra

I am new to chef and have been struggling to find best practices on how to configure application configuration in an environment cookbook [source #1].

The environment cookbook I'm working on should do the following:

- Prepare the node for a custom application deployment by creating directories, users, etc. that are specific for this deployment only.
- Add initialization and monitoring scripts specific for the application deployment.
- Define the application configuration settings.

This last responsibility has been a particularly tough nut to crack.

An example configuration file of an application deployment might look as follows:

```
{
    "server": {
        "port": 9090
    },
    "session": {
        "proxy": false,
        "expires": 100
    },
    "redis": [{
        "port": 9031,
        "host": "rds01.prd.example.com"
    }, {
        "port": 9031,
        "host": "rds02.prd.example.com"
    }],
    "ldapConfig": {
        "url": "ldap://example.inc:389",
        "adminDn": "CN=Admin,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=inc",
        "adminUsername": "user",
        "adminPassword": "secret",
        "searchBase": "OU=BigCustomer,OU=customers,DC=example,DC=inc",
        "searchFilter": "(example=*)"
    },
    "log4js": {
        "appenders": [
            {
                "category": "[all]",
                "type": "file",
                "filename": "./logs/myapp.log"
            }
        ],
        "levels": {
            "[all]": "ERROR"
        }
    },
    "otherService": {
        "basePath" : "http://api.prd.example.com:1234/otherService",
        "smokeTestVariable" : "testVar"
    }
}
```

Some parts of this deployment configuration file are more stable than others. While this may vary depending on the application and setup, things like port numbers and usernames I prefer to keep the same across environments for simplicity's sake.

Let me classify the configuration settings:

*Stable properties*

- session
- server
- log4js.appenders
- ldapConfig.adminUsername
- ldapConfig.searchFilter
- otherService.basePath
- redis.port

*Environment specific properties*

- log4js.levels
- otherService.smokeTestVariable

*Partial-environment specific properties*

- redis.host: `rds01.[environment].example.com`
- otherService.basePath: `http://api.[environment].example.com:1234/otherService`

*Encrypted environment specific properties*

- ldapConfig.adminPassword

**Questions**

1. How should I create the configuration file? Some options: 1) use a file shipped within the application deployment itself, 2) use a cookbook file template, 3) use a JSON blob as one of the attributes [source #2], 4)... other?
2. There is a great diversity of variability in the configuration file; how best to manage these using Chef? Roles, environments, per-node configuration, data-bags, encrypted data-bags...? Or should I opt for environment variables instead?

Some key concerns in the approach:

- I would prefer there is only 1 way to set the configuration settings.
- Changing the configuration file for a developer should be fairly straightforward (they are using Vagrant on their local machines before pushing to test).
- The passwords must be secure.
- The chef cookbook is managed within the same git repository as the sourcecode.
- Some configuration settings require a great deal of flexibility; for example the `log4js` setting in my example config might contain many more `appender`s with dozens of fairly unstructured variables.

Any experiences would be much appreciated!

**Sources**

1. http://blog.vialstudios.com/the-environment-cookbook-pattern/
2. http://lists.opscode.com/sympa/arc/chef/2013-01/msg00392.html
3. http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2013/01/28/local-templates-for-application-configuration/
4. http://realityforge.org/code/2012/11/12/reusable-cookbooks-revisited.html

Answer (score 4):

Jamie Winsor gave a talk at chefconf that goes further in explaining the [environment cookbook pattern's](http://blog.vialstudios.com/the-environment-cookbook-pattern/) rationale and usage:

- [Chefcon: talking about self-contained releases, using chef](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dq_vGxd-jps)
- [Slides](http://www.slideshare.net/resetexistence/chef-conf2014)

In my opinion one of the key concepts this pattern introduces is the idea of using [chef environments](https://docs.chef.io/environments.html) to control the settings of each application **instance**. The environment is updated, using [berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com/), with the run-time version of the cookbooks being used by the application.

What is less obvious is that if you decide to reserve a chef environment for the use of a single application instance, it then it becomes safe to use that environment to configure the application's global run-time settings.

An example if given in the berkshelf-api [installation instructions](https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf-api).  There you will see production environment (for the application) being edited with various run-time settings:

```
knife environment edit berkshelf-api-production
```

In conclusion, chef gives us lots of options. I would make the following generic recommendations:

1. Capture defaults in the application cookbook
2. Create an environment for each application instance (as recommended by pattern)
3. Set run-time attribute over-rides in the environment

Notes:

- See also the [berksflow](https://github.com/reset/berkflow) tool. Designed to make the environment cookbook pattern easier to implement.
- I have made no mention of using roles. These can also be used to override attributes at run-time, but might be simpler to capture everything in a dedicated chef environment. Roles seem better suited to capturing information peculiar to a component of an application.